# Element targeting where onclick has occurred in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a HTML section with multiple list elements as such:

```
<li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown @DropdownClass" @onclick="dropMenu">

<li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown @DropdownClass" @onclick="dropMenu">

<li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown @DropdownClass" @onclick="dropMenu">
```

The goal is that when one of the elements is clicked on, a new class `c-show` is added which then show the submenu's underneath.

My code in blazor to add this is:

```
@code{
    bool MenuDroppedDown = true;
    string DropdownClass => MenuDroppedDown ? "c-show" : "";


    public async void dropMenu()
    {
        MenuDroppedDown = !MenuDroppedDown;
    }
}
```

But the problem here is that once an element is clicked on, then `c-show` is added everywhere.

How can I have it so only the element where the *onclick* event occurred is affected?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the code below into the Index component, add this amazing css class

```
.c-show {
background-color: red;
}
```

to the site.css located in the wwwroot folder, and run the code

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
         <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown @item.DropdownClass" @onclick="@(() => item.MenuDroppedDown = !item.MenuDroppedDown)" >click me</li>
    }

</ul>


@code{

List<LiTag> items = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new LiTag { ID = i }).ToList();

public class LiTag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool MenuDroppedDown { get; set; }
    public string DropdownClass => MenuDroppedDown ? "c-show" : "";
}
}
```

Please don't hesitate to ask questions, as this code is rather self-explanatory, I did not bother to explain what I was doing.

Comment: Just be aware there is an issue with inline lambda expressions in Server Side Blazor, that can cause network traffic to blow up. It is currently safer to add a `Click` method to the "item" and bind that directly `@onclick=item.Click` - they both work, but this method avoids the network traffic issue. bonus points if you add `@key=item` as well so Blazor can track each `li` more accurately

Comment: @MisterMagoo I am curious about this issue. Could you please share some information about it (or a link to the issue on github)?

Comment: @Guilherme Sure - here you go https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17886

Comment: It's really easy to test as described in that issue, so you can confirm or deny of it is a problem for you.